# If an entire function $f$ satisfies $|f(z)| \le |\log z|,$ what can we say about $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. Define $\Omega=\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$, the complex plane with the ray $(-\infty,0]$ removed. Suppose that for all $z \in \Omega$ , $|f(z)| \le |\log z|$, where $\log z$ is the principal branch of the logarithm. What can one conclude about the function $f$?

My try:

I am tempted to use Cauchy's Integral formula and use the given bound. Since $f$ is entire , $f(z)$ can be represented as $$f(z)=f(0)+zf'(0)+...$$
Now $$f^n(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$, where $\gamma: |z|=r$     . Then taking modulus on both the sides and using the inequality we arrive at $$|f^n(0)| \le \frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{|f(re^{i\theta})|}{r^{n+1}}r d\theta$$   . Everything is fine till now. Now when I try to use the given inequality, I am stuck. I believe I simply can't use $|f(re^{i\theta})| \le |\log (re^{i\theta})|$ everywhere in the contour since the branch of logarithm doesn't exist at the point $(-r,0)$. Even if I am able to do that (something tells me I should be but don't know what) , I will end up with $f(z)$ being a constant. Then $f(1)=0$ would give $f$ to be identically $0$ everywhere.

My question is why should I be able to use the inequality through out the contour(if at all it is possible)?? If not, then what are the other ways of proceeding??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You should make use of this fact that $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\frac{f(z)}z=0$ and then apply Liouville...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is continuous. Then
$$|f(-r)|\le\ln r+\pi$$
for $r>0$.